# Include vs. ThenInclude for grandchild properties in EF Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Is one of these approaches preferred for loading grandchildren properties? I like how succinct the first is, but I don't know if it's more costly.

```
return source
    .Include(x => x.Server)
    .Include(x => x.Server.User)
    .Include(x => x.Server.ParentServer)
    .Include(x => x.Server.DataCenter);
```

or

```
return source
    .Include(x => x.Server)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.User)
    .Include(x => x.Server)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.ParentServer)
    .Include(x => x.Server)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.DataCenter);
```

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent. The first one is obviously preferred, but it's not possible with collection navigations. Hence, ThenInclude().

```
// Won't compile
return source
    .Include(x => x.Posts.Authors)
    .Include(x => x.Posts.Comments);

// Compiles
return source
    .Include(x => x.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Authors)
    .Include(x => x.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Comments);
```

But, if you want to give up compile-time type safety, you can also just use the string overloads.

```
// Compiles, may throw
return source
    .Include("Posts.Authors")
    .Include("Posts.Comments");
```

But please, don't do this...

```
// Over-thinking it ;-)
return source
    .Include(nameof(Blog.Posts) + "." + nameof(Post.Authors))
    .Include(nameof(Blog.Posts) + "." + nameof(Post.Comments));
```

Comment: As an aside, EF6 supported this: `source.Include(x => x.Posts.Select(y => y.Comments))` (but we didn't like it)

Answer (score 1):

That's a very interesting question ! This point isn't documented at all if EF (Core) docs.

A few weeks ago I ran some tests about this and my conclusion was that there's no difference between those methods.

I tried dozens of scenarios, from the simplest and dumbest ones to a 8 level relations hierarchy, and the generated SQL request were always **100% identical**.

Then I had a look EF Core's source code and found no real differences between `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` implementations.

So my answer is not 100% affirmative, maybe I'm missing something, but, I think that both methods are identical.

If you want a definitive answer, I think that the best way is to ask your question on [EF Core's repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore).

Comment: No need to submit an issue. We're always watching... 

Comment: That's great, thanks for clarifying that, I forgot the little difference with collection navigations